# How to use batching in OrientDB using Java

Tags: java, orientdb

I am new to `OrientDB`, and I am wondering how to use batch and massive write/insert in the `Java` native driver. I couldn't find any examples in `Java`.

UPDATE

Since I am using `Document API`, so using the massive insertions is simply

```
db.declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert());
//your code here....
db.declareIntent(null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a small example

```
OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph(yourPath); 

    String cmd = "begin\n";
    cmd += "LET source = SELECT FROM V WHERE id = 'zz'\n";
    cmd += "LET target = SELECT FROM V WHERE id = 'yy'\n";
    cmd += "LET edge = CREATE EDGE RELATION FROM $source TO $target\n";
    cmd += "commit";

g.command(new OCommandScript("sql", cmd)).execute();
```

Hope it helps